# Deriving a multivariate chain rule

Tags: calculus

Suppose $u = f(x, y)$ and $(x, y) = g(r, s, t)$ where f and g are differentiable
functions. For part (ii), also suppose that f has continuous second order
partial derivatives.

(i) Write down the chain rule for $(f ◦ g)'$ and use it to derive formulas for
$u_{r}$, $u_{s}$ and $u_{t}$
. (Just drawing tree diagrams is not enough here, the general chain rule needed to be used).

(ii) Suppose $x = r^2 − s^2$
, $y = 2rs$. Express $U_{sr}$ in terms of x, y, and partial
derivatives of u with respect to $x$ and $y$.

What i did

I know that $x,y$ is a component of $u$ and $r,s,t$ is a component of $u$

$(f ◦ g)'$= $(f( g(r, s, t))'$ =$f'g(r, s, t)$$g'(r, s, t)$

Then substituting in $x$ and $y$ i got

$(f ◦ g)'$=$f'g(r(x,y), s(x,y), t(x,y))$$g'(r(x,y), s(x,y), t(x,y))$ and im unsure

Whether it is correct and how to continue from here. Could anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what you know. $u=f(x,y)$. But, at the same time, $x=x(r,s,t) \wedge y=y(r,s,t).$ So you've $f(x(r,s,t),y(r,s,t))$. Which is the same as $f(g(r,s,t))=f \circ g.$ Now, both variables $x \wedge y$ are functions of $r, s$ and $t$.

So $$u_r = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}. $$

With the other variables $s,t$ you can use a similar argument.

Suppose $x=r^2-s^2, y=2rs$ in your first problem. Then you have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(2r)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(2s),$$

because $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = 2r$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=2s.$

I'll let the rest for you.